# What are rules behind setting model's child attributes to null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC / Thymeleaf application I apply an UUID when instantiating a brand new instance of any model entity (I do it in an AbstractModel that each entity extends). I use it then for custom equals method implementation that spreads along all entities

```
@Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String uuid = IdGenerator.createId();
```

I some other place I create a form bean (simple wrapper) containing a graph of such newly created entities.

an example wrapper would look like this:

```
WrapperObj obj = new Obj(new FooEntity(), new BarEntity())
```

both FooEntity and BarEntity have some fileds like ints, Strings etc. that are initially not set. The only fileld that is set isthe UUID

Then I pass the wrapper to the form where I eventually fill up the empty fields.

When I submit the form and the entities are not modified, they still exist in  the wrapper. When I attach another object the the wrapper `WrapperObj obj = new Obj(new FooEntity(), new BarEntity(), new TestObj())` that has no UUID initially set and submit the form without changing it's fields, the TestObj is reset to null.

This is my desired behaviour for the other UUID-enabled entities.

How can I instruct the spring mvc framework to ignore the UUID field at the binding time so that the entities also become null when not modified?

Thanks for your help!

**CORRECTION**

the TestObj object was not bound to any input field in the form.

**UPDATE**

I have just discovered that it is not the uuid that causes the problem. I my wrapper I have another child entity, let's say BoolFoo that has only boolean fields (apart of the id(int) and uuid(string) set by the AbstractEntity class).
Those fields are of type checkbox within the form. 
When I submit the form without modifying any of BoolFoo's fileds, BoolFoo as a whole is set to null (although the id and uuid are present when passing the object to the form).

However, if there is at least one text field(did not checked against other types) provided for any child entity, the child object (or any actually) will never be null when comming back from the form.
I've tried already the `binder.setDisallowedFields("uuid")` approach as well as `binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));` but no matter what I do, the unmodified objects will not be set to null.

Looks like there are different rules when it comes to different form field types in spring mvc.

Has anyone come across similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataBinder` has two properties named `allowedFields` and `disallowedFields` that you could define what to bind or not. Just use that with annotation `@InitBinder` before executing controller method:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("uuid");
}
```

Comment: according to the latest API documentation :

`Register fields that should not be allowed for binding. Default is none. Mark fields as disallowed for example to avoid unwanted modifications by malicious users when binding HTTP request parameters.`

I don't actually bind the uuid by any form field, it's just passed to the form as part of each entity within the wrapper. In the update I described my latest observations.